# Como detectar alterações do MySQL no NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, node.js, log

Boa noite,

alguém já utilizou esse package ou conhece algum similar e que funcione?

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events

- Objetivo: lançar um evento quando houver alguma alteração na database.
  Antes dava erro dizendo que não era permitido monitorar meu binlog, aí ajeitei e não da mais erro, mas não funciona.
- Meu arquivo de log fica em: **C:/xampp/mysql/data**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse plugin parece estar bem documentado. Qual foi o código que correste e não funcionou?

Comment: Verdade, está bem documentado, o suficiente... mas apenas não funciona.

É a parte do Quick Start, só tem aquilo '-'

Comment: Podes colocar na pergunta a tua implementação desse exemplo, ou seja o que tens e não funciona?

Comment: É porque deixei no trabalho :/.

Mas tá igual àquilo do exemplo, só muda o Host, User e Password, que eu até já me conectei no package de MySQL do NodeJS e a já fiz tudo no banco, não teve problemas..

Não difere daí, só estava pensando que poderia ser nos arquivos, por isso até botei a foto.

Comment: Como está a tua base de dados? Há dois parametros de configuração importantes que no exemplo estão com `'myDB.table.field.value'` e `'match this string or regex'`, mas que precisas adaptar...

Comment: Pois é, esses aí eu troquei, estavam iguais.

'nodejs_db.posts.content.value' e 'Teste'.

Eu alterava o valor na DB pra 'Teste' e mesmo assim nada '-'.

Comment: Eu já usei https://github.com/numtel/mysql-live-select. Para funcionar, é necessário habilitar o binlog do MySQL.

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver, sua aplicação tem essa rotina responsiva, ou seja, fazer algo automaticamente quando uma ação qualquer ocorrer. Correto?

Se o seu servidor Web oferecer suporte, eu sugiro você utilizar `WebSocket` para fazer exatamente isso que você precisa.

O cliente, ao conectar na sua aplicação irá criar uma *conexão persistente*, que existirá enquanto ele estiver logado. Dessa forma, você pode responder do servidor para um determinado cliente (ou vários) sempre quando a rotina que você espera for executada.

Você pode também utilizar o `Spring-WebSocket` pra facilitar a sua implementação. Também pode utilizar alguma API como `SocketJS` ou `Socket.io` em Javascript.

Abraço.

> The Spring Framework provides a WebSocket API designed to adapt to
>   various WebSocket engines. Currently the list includes WebSocket
>   runtimes such as Tomcat 7.0.47+, Jetty 9.1+, GlassFish 4.1+, WebLogic
>   12.1.3+, and Undertow 1.0+ (and WildFly 8.0+). Additional support may be added as more WebSocket runtimes become available.

Fontes:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html
- http://g00glen00b.be/spring-angular-sockjs/
- http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html